# SQL: how to select greatest occurrence between 2 dates from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

For the example table:

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, d DATE);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES
(1,'Tom', '2020-01-01'),
(2,'Lucy','2020-01-01'),
(3,'Frank', '2020-03-01'),
(4,'Jane', '2020-03-01'),
(5,'Robert', '2020-03-01');
```

While doing a SELECT count(*)

there are 2 rows for the clause
`WHERE d ='2020-01-01'`

and 3 for
 `WHERE d > '2020-01-01'`

i am trying to select the results having the greater count.

i have tried inner joining and using the GREATEST function but i feel like i am missing understanding of some basic concept.

EDIT:
Basically, i need to find the greatest between number of rows betwen date 1 & date 2 and date1 and date3,

Any help?

Comment: what are date 1, date 2, date 3 & date 4?  You mentioned them in your edit but and it's now even less clear what you're asking. the best way to get answers to sql questions is to provide a sample of data (which you've done) and the desired result.  The desired result is what's missing here.

Comment: What should the desired result look like? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What do you refer to as `date1`, `date2` and `date3`? Which result do you want for this data? As it stands, your question is rather unclear and not likely to get a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT` do what yo want:

```
select d, count(*)
from names
group by d
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

If you want the detailed names, I would suggest using `group_concat()`:

```
select d, group_concat(name) as names, count(*)
from names
group by d
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! What if i want to specify a range of dates. i think this is giving me the count for individual dates.

Comment: @aryan . . . This answers the question that you asked as I understand it.

Comment: well, i said  "d > 2020-01-01" so i am expecting multiple dates for that column. Basically, i need to find the greatest between number of rows betwen date 1 & date 2 and date1 and date3,